# Extracting data from data frame

Tags: r, dataframe, reshape

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
    Code           ID          X1         X2
1  1000             2         1.6       250.6
2  1000             3         0.15      340.9
3  1001             2         0.53      441.7
4  1001             3         1.8       499.0
5  1002             2         4.4       516.6
6  1003             3         4.9       616.6
```

What I would like to do is to create a new data frame with unique codes and each unique ID as a column (there are two unique IDs:2 and 3), with the corresponding X1 and X2 values, so the result should look like this:

```
    Code           ID2X1       ID2X2      ID3X1       ID3X2
1  1000             1.6        250.6        0.15      340.9
2  1001            0.53        441.7         1.8      499.0
5  1002             4.4        516.6          NA         NA
6  1003             NA            NA         4.9      616.6
```

I used the "unique" function to extract the unique codes so I have the first column, but couldn't think of an efficient way to extract the data. Please note that some of the codes don't have values for either ID2 or ID3.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is a basic `reshape` problem, reshaping from "long" to "wide".

Try the following (assuming your `data.frame` is called "mydf"):

```
reshape(mydf, idvar="Code", timevar="ID", direction = "wide")
#   Code X1.2  X2.2 X1.3  X2.3
# 1 1000 1.60 250.6 0.15 340.9
# 3 1001 0.53 441.7 1.80 499.0
# 5 1002 4.40 516.6   NA    NA
# 6 1003   NA    NA 4.90 616.6
```

Answer (score 1):

Using `dplyr` and `tidyr`

```
 library(dplyr)
 library(tidyr)
  mydf%>% 
  gather(Var, Val, X1:X2) %>%
  mutate(IDVar=paste0("ID", ID, Var)) %>%
  select(-ID, -Var) %>% 
  spread(IDVar, Val)
  #  Code ID2X1 ID2X2 ID3X1 ID3X2
 #1 1000  1.60 250.6  0.15 340.9
 #2 1001  0.53 441.7  1.80 499.0
 #3 1002  4.40 516.6    NA    NA
 #4 1003    NA    NA  4.90 616.6
```