# Find interval from data frame start and end points

Tags: r, dataframe, intervals

I have the data frame (DF):

```
Start  End  Result
2      300  FL91
5      250  FL12
550    750  FL18
720    900  FL41
```

I want to find all "Results" that are between "Start" < 81 > "End" (So, I want to find all "Results" that lies on the interval with "Start and "End" points less than 81.
I tried:

```
y <- 81
findInterval(y, DF$Start, DF$End)
```

But I got such errors: 'vec' must be sorted non-decreasingly and not contain NAs.
I am sure that my data frame does not contain NA and is not sorted decreasingly.
I also tried to use suggestions from the similar topics but cannot figure out the solution.

[Extracting data from data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24616094/extracting-data-from-data-frame)

[Interval search on a data frame](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11705765/interval-search-on-a-data-frame)

So, what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a ready-built function or create your own:

```
findInt <- function(value, start, end) {
  start < value & end > value
}

indx <- findInt(81, DF$Start, DF$End)
DF$Result[indx]
#[1] "FL91" "FL12"
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe something like this

```
[1]  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE
> df[df[,1] <= 81 & 81 <=  df[,2], 3]
[1] FL91 FL12
```